# Redirecting and writing in the same file

Tags: linux, unix, sed

Hi i have a script which replaces the certain occurrences in the .sql files and after that writes it in the some new file.So,i m here unnecessarily creating extra files.Is there anyway by which i can write in the same file.

Below is the part of the script:

```
sed "s/v1/$value1/g" Save.sql >> CreateViewFinal1.sql
sed "s/v2/$value2/g" CreateViewFinal1.sql >> CreateViewFinal2.sql
sed "s/v3/$value3/g" CreateViewFinal2.sql >> CreateViewFinal3.sql
sed "s/v4/$value4/g" CreateViewFinal3.sql >> CreateViewFinal4.sql
sed "s/v5/$value5/g" CreateViewFinal4.sql >> CreateViewFinal5.sql
sed "s/v6/$value6/g" CreateViewFinal5.sql >> CreateViewFinal6.sql
sed "s/v7/$value7/g" CreateViewFinal6.sql >> CreateViewFinal7.sql
sed "s/v8/$value8/g" CreateViewFinal7.sql >> CreateViewFinal8.sql
sed "s/v9/$value9/g" CreateViewFinal8.sql >> CreateViewFinal9.sql
sed "s/a1/$value10/g" CreateViewFinal9.sql >> CreateViewFinal10.sql
sed "s/b1/$value11/g" CreateViewFinal10.sql >> CreateViewFinal11.sql
sed "s/c1/$value12/g" CreateViewFinal11.sql >> CreateViewFinal12.sql


sqlplus -S -L cimkroger/cimkroger@orcl @CreateViewFinal12.sql
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sed's inline editing and can avoid multiple sed commands with `-e` switch like this:

```
sed -i.bak -e "s/v1/$value1/g" -e "s/v2/$value2/g" -e "s/v3/$value3/g" Save.sql
```

Comment: `-i` is the switch for inline editing and `.bak` is the extension of backup file that gets created in this process.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

You can change a file directly with the `-i` option of `sed`.

Hence, `sed -i .... file` will replace something in the same file.

Moreover, instead of so many `sed` different lines, you can do multiple `sed` actions with the `-e` option. So instead of:

```
sed "s/v1/$value1/g" Save.sql >> CreateViewFinal1.sql
sed "s/v2/$value2/g" CreateViewFinal1.sql >> CreateViewFinal2.sql
sed "s/v3/$value3/g" CreateViewFinal2.sql >> CreateViewFinal3.sql
```

You can do

```
sed -i -e "s/v1/$value1/g" -e "s/v2/$value2/g" -e "s/v3/$value3/g" Save.sql
```

and so on.

#### Example

```
$ cat file
hello you
$ sed -i -e 's/hello/bye/g' -e 's/you/me/g' file
$ cat file
bye me
```

Comment: sed -i -e "s/v1/$value1/g" -e "s/v2/$value2/g" -e "s/v3/$value3/g" Save.sql   din't worked properly!! anyways thanks for the suggestions

Comment: coz i  somewhere i was assigning v1=value1,i mislead and wrote "v1=value11"...which got carried in the whole script and it crashed...but after ur comment ....again go through the script n got to knw its my mistek n not the command mistek